# linking bullet include directory with cmake

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, include-path, bullet

I have a common problem, "include not found". While I was using the command line to set the includes and libraries directories everything was fine,
Quote:

```
g++ src/B_engine.cc -lLinearMath -lBulletSoftBody -lBulletCollision -lBulletDynamics -I/usr/include/bullet -o a.out
```

but I need to make it working with cmake, there is a copy of my current cmake,

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 2.8 )
project( a.out )
set( SOURCES src/B_engine.cc )
set( EXECUTABLE_NAME a.out )
find_package( Bullet REQUIRED )
add_executable( ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} ${SOURCES} )
add_definitions(-std=c++11)
```

when I do a "ccmake .", I see :

```
BULLET_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/include/bullet
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr/local
```

so, me (with the command line) and cmake are expecting to use /usr/include/bullet as directory. But when I do "make", I get this error :

```
[100%]
Scanning dependencies of target a.out
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/a.out.dir/src/B_engine.cc.o
In file included from /home/user/test/src/B_engine.cc:2:0:/home/user/test/src/B_engine.hh:5:36: fatal error: btBulletDynamicsCommon.h: No such file or directory
 #include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>
```

I do not understand why the g++ command line and cmake doesn't give the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the find_package script for Bullet only locates the include dir but does not add it to the include list.
So I'd add it explicitly:

```
include_directories(${BULLET_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Comment: You can remove the "maybe" :) I don't think any `find_package` calls explicitly to include_directories

Comment: I had written an alternative answer suggesting to include specifying some part of the path (`#include <bullet/btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>`), but at a second thought it doesn't make much sense because [that files includes more files](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/btBulletDynamicsCommon_8h.html), without that directory specifier. So the answer of hank is the only one correct.

Comment: thx hank, I gave up yesterday because of this issue. Waiting somebody to save me! You did it! my hero! PS for other people : I also needed to add the libraries in the way to compile

Comment: just to mention that this line should be before the find_package command